# Keybindings not working properly in 17.10

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 17.10

Seems like whenever a text box in any application or webpage is in focus I cannot use any shortcut. For example, while typing this from Google Chrome, `Ctrl+W` won't close this page. Nor will global shortcuts like `Ctrl+Space` to launch Synapse work.

I believe the problem has something to do with libinput. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!